# I don't know how to add squares in Java using arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a beginner in java and I am stuck. Please help me thank you! So this is my code so far.  The program should asks the user to for a max number and then the program should calculate each number from 1 to the maximum along with the square. And then at the end it should add them up.

Please enter the max number:

5

Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0

Arr1 1 Arr2 1 Arr3 1

Arr1 5 Arr2 5 Arr3 5

Arr1 14 Arr2 14 Arr3 14

Arr1 30 Arr2 30 Arr3 30

Arr1 55 Arr2 55 Arr3 55

Sum of Squares is 55

But when I do it all the Arr have 0s and the sum is 0

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SumSquareArr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the max number: ");
        int max = input.nextInt();
        int[]arr1 = new int[max+1];
        int[]arr2 = new int[max+1];
        int[]arr3 = new int[max+1];
        int total = 0;
        int i = 1;
        // For-loop to calculate 
        for (i = 1;i <= max;i++){
            int square; 
            square = i*i;
            arr1[square] = arr1[i-1] + i;
            i = 1;
            // While-loop to calculate
            while (i <= max) {
                arr2[square] = arr2[i-1] + i;
                i++;
            }
            i = 1;
            // Do-While-loop to calculate
            do
            arr3[square] = arr3[i-1] + i;
            while (++i <= max);
            for (i = 0; i <= max; i++)
            System.out.println("Arr1 " + arr1[i] + " Arr2 " + arr2[i] + " Arr3 " + arr3[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of Squares is " + arr1[total]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `{}` around all blocks. There's some odd bracketing going on in your code.

Comment: Where are you stuck? What about adding squares don't you know? What's not working correctly, and what have you tried to fix it? What's your question?

Comment: The output should look like this :
Please enter the max number:5
Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Arr1 1 Arr2 1 Arr3 1
Arr1 5 Arr2 5 Arr3 5
Arr1 14 Arr2 14 Arr3 14
Arr1 30 Arr2 30 Arr3 30
Arr1 55 Arr2 55 Arr3 55
Sum of Square is 55 
but it comes out like this:Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Arr1 1 Arr2 5 Arr3 5
Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Arr1 0 Arr2 0 Arr3 0
Sum of Squares is 0

Comment: Click "edit" below your question, and add that output to your post. You can then format it to be much more readable.

Comment: I am having difficulty how to make the Array part add the sqaures

Comment: You'll probably get better/more answers if you're more specific.

Comment: I edited my question again...does it help? It's because I am clueless!

Comment: What are "arr1" "arr2" and "arr3"?  naming variables like that is a recipe for disaster.  I imagine one of them might be "squares" and the other "sumOfSquares" but it's not clear.

Comment: I seriously recommend that before you go any further in your programming career, you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: @Taylor - the reason for `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` is that OP is learning about the different types of loop.  He/she uses a `for` loop, a `while` loop and a `do-while` loop to solve the same problem, and writes the results from each loop into one of the three arrays.  Unfortunately, he/she has messed up the nesting - the `while` and the `do-while` are not supposed to be inside the `for`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks for pointing that out, but the fact remains, generic variable names suck. ;)

Comment: @Taylor I don't dispute that.  But maybe if he/she learns about loops today, he/she will learn about appropriate variable names tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
arr1[square] = arr1[i-1] + i;
```

should say

```
arr1[i] = arr1[i-1] + square;
```

Similarly with `arr2` and `arr3`.

You're also missing a `}` after `arr1[square] = arr1[i-1] + i;` and missing a `{` before `System.out.println("Arr1 " + arr1[i] + " Arr2 " + arr2[i] + " Arr3 " + arr3[i]);`

Once you've got your loops nested properly, you'll need to repeat `square = i*i;` inside the `while` loop and the `do-while` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! That really helped. I can't believe it was that simple. :)

Comment: Umm, yes, I guess you would.  Or you could declare it outside the loops.